# How does a MOSFET behave with a very thin substrate?

Tags: cmos, layout

I'm considering a MOSFET with a very short distance between the gate and the bottom of the substrate (body connection), shorter than the channel length. How will the channel form and behave in this case?

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: The question is not very clear currently, since it's hard to understand and visualize your assumptions and the scenario in question. Can you add labeled diagrams to your question?

Comment: I meant the length is the space form G to the bottom of the substrate. what happen with the channel if the length is shorter than spacing of S to D?

Comment: @mitruong I've gone ahead and summarized that as an [revision](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/577043/revisions) to your question since users might not see comments in all cases. Please feel free to [edit] further or roll back if you are dissatisfied with the edit.

Comment: It sounds like you want to create some kind of SOI structure, possibly FDSOI. You can do some research on those kinds of MOSFETs.